# parse Hash "#" as string in URL request in flask routes

Tags: python, url, flask, url-routing

I am trying to parse "#" symbol as a direct url in Flask project. The issue is everytime the url is requested, it breaks any value that has # init as it's a special character in url encoding.

```
localhost:9999/match/keys?source=#123&destination=#123
```

In flask, I am trying to get these arguments like this

```
app.route(f'/match/keys/source=<string:start>/destination=<string:end>', methods=['GET'])
```

The url response that i see on console is this:

```
"GET /match/keys/source=' HTTP/1.0" 404 -] happens
```

Comment: try using `%23` for the '#' character

Comment: pls note that you catch query strings in flask like so ```request.args.get('source')```

Comment: I don't think that route is a valid route also it should be `/match/keys, methods=['GET']` and you use the `request.args.get('source')` to get your query string values

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might not fully understand how 'query strings' work in flask. This url:

```
app.route(f'/match/keys/source=<string:start>/destination=<string:end>', methods=['GET'])
```

won't work as you expect as it won't match the request:

```
localhost:9999/match/keys?source=#123&destination=#123
```

rather it aught to be:

```
@app.route('/match/keys', methods=['GET'])
```

and this would match:

```
localhost:9999/match/keys?source=%23123&destination=%23123
```

Then to catch those 'query strings' you do:

```
source = request.args.get('source') # <- name the variable what you may
destination = request.args.get('destination') # <- same as the naming format above
```

So when you call `localhost:9999/match/keys?source=%23123&destination=%23123` you test for those 'query strings' in the request url and if they are they that route function would execute.

I wrote this test:

```
def test_query_string(self):
    with app.test_client() as c:
        rc = c.get('/match/keys?source=%23123') # <- Note use of the '%23' to represent '#'
        print('Status code: {}'.format(rc.status_code))
        print(rc.data)
        assert rc.status_code == 200
        assert 'source' in request.args
        assert rc.data.decode('utf-8') == "#123"
```

and it passes using this route function:

```
@app.route('/match/keys', methods=['GET'])
def some_route():
    s = request.args.get('source')

    return s
```

So you see I was able to catch the query string source value in my unit test.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I actually found another way to work around with it.

Comment: Instead of getting a GET method, I am requesting a POST Method now.

Answer (score 0):

I found another trick to work around with it. Instead of using GET method, I switched to POST

```
localhost:9999/match/keys
```

and in the app.routes, i sent the argument to get_json.

```
app.route('/match/keys/',method=['POST'])
def my_func():
    arg = request.get_json
```

In postman, I send the POST request and send the body to be like this: 
[Postman Post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UczOO.png)